# How to make animated toggle menu with effect only on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new here and forgive me if this question has already been asked before, but I couldn't find that kind of problem. And at the beginning, sorry for my grammar ;) .

The thing is, that I would like to get toggle menu that slides in from right side, after a click on the "hamburger" icon, but only when the width of the screen is smaller than 576 px. On larger screens, i have a fixed-top navbar, without any effects and that's fine. I am using Bootstrap 4 to build my site. Is it possible to do?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand pl-md-4" href="index.html">Logo</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 4</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav pr-md-4">
                <li class="nav-item px-md-3">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">link 5</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item px-md-3">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">link 6</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">link 7</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I think you want something like this: https://codepen.io/JacobLett/pen/ryLrJP

Comment: That is exacly what I need, thank you very much :) do I need to attach any library to my html to get that effect?

Comment: On the CodePen page, click the cog icons next to CSS and JS to see which libraries are in use.

Comment: It worked, thanks! :) have a good day :)

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do it is create two different navs one for the Bigger screens and one more for smaller screens.And give different functionality based on the ID through JS

```
<!-- Hide the for large Screen -->
  <nav id="jsIdentifer1" class="hidden-md hidden-lg">
   your navigation code 
  </nav>
<!-- Hide the for small Screen -->
  <nav id="jsIdentifer2" class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">
    your navigation code 
  </nav>
```

Comment: thanks for your very fast respond, but I've already used off Canvas :)